# Euler 23 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

All right. I think I have the right idea to find the solution to Euler #23 (The one about finding the sum of all numbers that can't be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers).

However, it is clear that one of my methods is too damn brutal.
How do you un-brute force this and make it work?

`sum_of_two_abunds?(num, array)` is the problematic method. I've tried pre-excluding certain numbers and it's still taking forever and I'm not even sure that it's giving the right answer.

```
def divsum(number)
  divsum = 1
  (2..Math.sqrt(number)).each {|i| divsum += i + number/i if number % i == 0}
  divsum -= Math.sqrt(number) if Math.sqrt(number).integer?
  divsum 
end

def is_abundant?(num)
  return true if divsum(num) > num
  return false
end

def get_abundants(uptonum) 
  abundants = (12..uptonum).select {|int| is_abundant?(int)}
end

def sum_of_two_abunds?(num, array)
  #abundant, and can be made from adding two abundant numbers.
  array.each do |abun1|
    array.each do |abun2|
      current = abun1+abun2

      break if current > num
      return true if current == num
    end
  end

  return false
end

def non_abundant_sum
  ceiling = 28123
  sum = (1..23).inject(:+) + (24..ceiling).select{|i| i < 945 && i % 2 != 0}.inject(:+)
  numeri = (24..ceiling).to_a
  numeri.delete_if {|i| i < 945 && i % 2 != 0}
  numeri.delete_if {|i| i % 100 == 0}
  abundants = get_abundants(ceiling)
  numeri.each {|numerus| sum += numerus if sum_of_two_abunds?(numerus, abundants) == false}
  return sum
end


start_time = Time.now

puts non_abundant_sum

#Not enough numbers getting excluded from the total. 
duration = Time.now - start_time

puts "Took #{duration} s "
```

Comment: How do i edit my post to fix my code blocks? Your formatting tool is cryptic.

Comment: I helped out. To enter a code block, simply indent your code 4 spaces (or use the `{}` button in the editor to do it for you). Also remember to indent Ruby code 2 spaces.

Comment: *"I'm not even sure that it's giving the right answer"* --- Why don't you write some test cases then?

Comment: Your optimization attempts just make this more complicated. You'd better get rid of them.

Comment: Also, and this is completely unrelated to your question (good luck), but in the `is_abundant?(num)` method, you basically do "return true if condition is true, else return false". For this type of thing, you can just return the evaluation of the condition itself...

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution 1

A simple way to make it a lot faster is to speed up your `sum_of_two_abunds?` method:

```
def sum_of_two_abunds?(num, array)
  array.each do |abun1|
    array.each do |abun2|
      current = abun1+abun2

      break if current > num
      return true if current == num
    end
  end

  return false
end
```

Instead of that inner loop, just ask the array whether it contains `num - abun1`:

```
def sum_of_two_abunds?(num, array)
  array.each do |abun1|
    return true if array.include?(num - abun1)
  end
  false
end
```

That's already faster than your Ruby code, since it's simpler and running faster C code. Also, now that that idea is clear, you can take advantage of the fact that the array is sorted and search `num - abun1` with binary search:

```
def sum_of_two_abunds?(num, array)
  array.each do |abun1|
    return true if array.bsearch { |x| num - abun1 <=> x }
  end
  false
end
```

And making that Rubyish:

```
def sum_of_two_abunds?(num, array)
  array.any? do |abun1|
    array.bsearch { |x| num - abun1 <=> x }
  end
end
```

Now you can get rid of your own special case optimizations and fix your incorrect `divsum` (which for example claims that `divsum(4)` is `5` ... you should really compare against a naive implementation that doesn't try any square root optimizations).

And then it should finish in well under a minute (about 11 seconds on my PC).

## Solution 2

Or you could instead ditch `sum_of_two_abunds?` entirely and just create all sums of two abundants and nullify their contribution to the sum:

```
def non_abundant_sum
  ceiling = 28123
  abundants = get_abundants(ceiling)
  numeri = (0..ceiling).to_a
  abundants.each { |a| abundants.each { |b| numeri[a + b] = 0 } }
  numeri.compact.sum
end
```

That runs on my PC in about 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked.  It seems that for some inexplicable reason, the square root of 4 isn't treated as a whole number.  So I changed it to check the modulo of the square root against zero instead.

Comment: @AaronGodhard Well, `integer?` is about the object type, not about the value: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Numeric.html#method-i-integer-3F You say "seems" to have worked. Did you not submit it to Project Euler yet to confirm? Btw, please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (Also for your previous question.)